# AntMatchers not working with POST method in Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security to set role permission. But it is only working with `GET` method. It returns 405 error when I'm using `POST` method.

I tried

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/admin/code/certificate/**/proc")
```

but it is not working.

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
            //# 페이지 접근 설정
            .antMatchers("/admin/login/**", "/admin/logout").permitAll()

            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/admin/code/certificate/**/proc")
                .access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_CERTIFICATE_EDIT', 'ROLE_CERTIFICATE_ALL')")
            .antMatchers("/admin/code/certificate/*", "/admin/code/certificate")
                .access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_CERTIFICATE_VIEW', 'ROLE_CERTIFICATE_EDIT', 'ROLE_CERTIFICATE_ALL')")
}
```

Comment: 405 means `method not allowed`, Could you share the controller ?

Comment: And you are using `hasAnyRole('ROLE_CERTIFICATE_EDIT', 'ROLE_CERTIFICATE_ALL')`, What's your role in your database ?

Comment: @PostMapping("/{id}/proc")
    public RedirectView certificateProc(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        RedirectAttributes attributes,
                                        @PathVariable(value = "id") int id,
                                        @RequestParam() HashMap<String, Object> params){

Comment: yes, i change method of form from post to get, it working.

Comment: But i want config security working with post form

Comment: Where is the `GET` method in your controller ?

Comment: i was try @RequestMapping(value="/{id}/proc", method= {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET}), but i not working